# You are not allowed to make changes or publish from 'Data Factory' mode as your factory has GIT enabled

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, azure-data-factory, paas

I am facing a issue.

I have a data factory with 20 piplines and dataset and linked services I enabled git with name xyz project and created adf-publish branch in that ,I worked almost 1 week in adf-publish branch. After one week my client is saying we have created new azure devops project with xyz1 prroject name.Now my changes is in adf-publish branch which comes under xyz project.

My question is that how can I save changes again ADF since I tried but I got a error 
You are not allowed to make changes or publish from 'Data Factory' mode as your factory has GIT enabled.

How can I populated the adf_publish branch changes to my adf -- then I will delete the adfpublish branch -- and again setup the repos to new project xyz1.

As u can see in this images I tried to change in my ADF but not able to publish it.

[image]

Thank
Anuj

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your scenario properly, but you will be able to commit directly to adf if you remove git from it.

To do that, go to the Data Factory overview and click on Git repo settings:

[image]

Then just click on Remove Git, at the bottom left of the new window that pops up.

After that you will be able to save changes directly, and also attach another git repo if thats what you need.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

In ADF, click on **Manage** tab -> Git configuration -> click on **disconnect**

[image]